# How to work with the tab layout items of a tab view

Tags: android

I have a tab layout file in which I have included two tabs. Here's the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/myTabHost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/first"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    layout="@layout/tab_layout1" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/second"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout="@layout/tab_layout2" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I have set up the tab host using the following code:

```
TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.myTabHost);
host.setup();

TabSpec firstSpec = themesHost.newTabSpec("tab_layout1");
firstSpec.setIndicator("layout1", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view));
firstSpec.setContent(R.id.first);
host.addTab(firstSpec);

TabSpec secondSpec = themesHost.newTabSpec("tab_layout2");
secondSpec.setIndicator("layout2", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view));
secondSpec.setContent(R.id.second);
host.addTab(secondSpec);
```

Although I can access the tab widgets layout items, when I want to do something like setting a background for each of the tabs layout I can't. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: first of all what is your mean about "doesn't work"? and second why you don't send `path` to `SecondActivity` and do this work in that activity?

Comment: It doesn't set the image and the page is blank when I run it. Also it's just a sample project. The reason goes back to my main app in which I have tabbed view and included other layouts as tab widgets and there I want to access the widgets items.

Comment: so what is the problem? when you set image, image not shown? you get `NPE` or what?

Comment: I don't get any exception. It just doesn't show the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting second activity and this activity inflates the second.xml again, It won't get your image set that you made in main activity. You need to set the image in second activity again.

Comment: You know as I explained to Shayan I don't want to set the image in my second activity. Take this as a sample and see if there is a way to show the image.

Comment: You can't set the image before create second activity. That's the way how it works. Unless you create a base activity class and inflate your all things in there and derive it to second class. Though it's wrong design in my opinion. The way you do now is you want to eat food before you buy.

Comment: Ok consider this: I have a layout file of an activity which has tabbed view and several tab widgets. I have included several layout files as the layout for each of these tab widgets and in my activity I have set the main layout file as the main content. Now I want to access the items in the other layout files as tab widgets. How do I do that? You have a better idea?